# How to connect to a Unix Domain Socket in .NET Core in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've created a unix socket in .NET Core on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
var unixSocket = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock";
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
```

Now how do I connect the socket?

The .NET Core API lists various [Socket.Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.net.sockets.socket#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Connect_System_Net_EndPoint_) options, but all except for the first one deal with IP Addresses:

```
public void Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
public void Connect(IPAddress address, int port)
public void Connect(IPAddress[] addresses, int port)
public void Connect(string host, int port)
```

The [System.Net API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.net#System_Net_EndpointPermission) defines a `DNSEndpoint` and an `IPEndpoint`, but I can't seem to find a `UnixEndpoint` or similar class to pass to `Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)`

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am using .NET core on Linux (updated my question to reflect this).  Surely there is a way to make the POSIX call to open a unix domain socket?  Please unmark this as duplicate, the marked duplicate does not relate to this question.

Comment: This is now available in .NET Standard 2.1 via [UnixDomainSocketEndPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.unixdomainsocketendpoint).

Comment: @MarkG Add that as an answer please, so that it can be chosen / upvoted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update: .NET Standard 2.1 / .NET Core 2.1 contains a [UnixDomainSocketEndPoint Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.unixdomainsocketendpoint?view=netstandard-2.1)**

Original answer, applies to versions of .NET Standard / .NET Core prior to 2.1:

There does not seem to be a built-in `UnixEndPoint` class for .NET Core or a library that implements one at the time of this writing.  The [UnixEndPoint class from the Mono.Posix](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix/UnixEndPoint.cs) project can be easily adapted to work with .NET Core, however:

```
// copied from https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix/UnixEndPoint.cs

//
// Mono.Unix.UnixEndPoint: EndPoint derived class for AF_UNIX family sockets.
//
// Authors:
//  Gonzalo Paniagua Javier (gonzalo@ximian.com)
//
// (C) 2003 Ximian, Inc (http://www.ximian.com)
//

//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
// a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
// "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
// without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
// distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
// permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
// the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
// included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
// EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
// MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
// NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
// LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
// OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
// WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//

using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace System.Net
{

    public class UnixEndPoint : EndPoint
    {
        string filename;

        public UnixEndPoint (string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("filename");

            if (filename == "")
                throw new ArgumentException ("Cannot be empty.", "filename");
            this.filename = filename;
        }

        public string Filename {
            get {
                return(filename);
            }
            set {
                filename=value;
            }
        }

        public override AddressFamily AddressFamily {
            get { return AddressFamily.Unix; }
        }

        public override EndPoint Create (SocketAddress socketAddress)
        {
            /*
             * Should also check this
             *
            int addr = (int) AddressFamily.Unix;
            if (socketAddress [0] != (addr & 0xFF))
                throw new ArgumentException ("socketAddress is not a unix socket address.");
            if (socketAddress [1] != ((addr & 0xFF00) >> 8))
                throw new ArgumentException ("socketAddress is not a unix socket address.");
             */

            if (socketAddress.Size == 2) {
                // Empty filename.
                // Probably from RemoteEndPoint which on linux does not return the file name.
                UnixEndPoint uep = new UnixEndPoint ("a");
                uep.filename = "";
                return uep;
            }
            int size = socketAddress.Size - 2;
            byte [] bytes = new byte [size];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
                bytes [i] = socketAddress [i + 2];
                // There may be junk after the null terminator, so ignore it all.
                if (bytes [i] == 0) {
                    size = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            string name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (bytes, 0, size);
            return new UnixEndPoint (name);
        }

        public override SocketAddress Serialize ()
        {
            byte [] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (filename);
            SocketAddress sa = new SocketAddress (AddressFamily, 2 + bytes.Length + 1);
            // sa [0] -> family low byte, sa [1] -> family high byte
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                sa [2 + i] = bytes [i];

            //NULL suffix for non-abstract path
            sa[2 + bytes.Length] = 0;

            return sa;
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return(filename);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode ()
        {
            return filename.GetHashCode ();
        }

        public override bool Equals (object o)
        {
            UnixEndPoint other = o as UnixEndPoint;
            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return (other.filename == filename);
        }
    }
}
```

With this class in your project, the socket can be connected like so:

```
var unixSocket = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock";
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
var unixEp = new UnixEndPoint(unixSocket);
socket.Connect(unixEp);
```

Comment: There's already a UnixDomainSocketEndpoint since .net core 2.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.unixdomainsocketendpoint?view=netcore-2.1#applies-to

Comment: @fbiagi could you please edit the answer and add some of the code from the docs into caleb answer? Because If I don't see your comment, It takes time for me to check the code that's caleb share... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```cs
using System.Net.Sockets;

var unixSocketName = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock";
var unixSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
unixSocket.Connect(new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(unixSocketName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I couldn't find a good example for unix sockets I designed my own.
Its very rudementary and has not many errorcatching, but it works.

Here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace mps.unix.socket
{

    public class UnixSocket
    {
        private Socket recvSocket;
        private string unixSocketpath;  // needed for cleanup
        private bool running = true;
        private byte[] data = new byte[0];

        public UnixSocket(string unixSocket)
        {
            this.unixSocketpath = unixSocket;
            this.recvSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified);

            System.IO.File.Delete(unixSocketpath);
            var ep = new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(unixSocketpath);
            recvSocket.Bind(ep);

            recvSocket.Listen();

            Thread w = new Thread(worker);
            w.Start();
        }

        private void worker()
        {
            while (this.running)
            {
                try
                {
                    var clientSocket = this.recvSocket.Accept();                        // waits for 'client' to 'connect'

                    Thread t = new Thread(delegate () { clientWorker(clientSocket); });
                    t.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }

        private void clientWorker(Socket s)
        {
            while (running)
            {
                byte[] d = new byte[s.ReceiveBufferSize];

                int length = s.Receive(d);

                lock (this.data)
                {
                    byte[] newData = new byte[this.data.Length + length];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(this.data, 0, newData, 0, this.data.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(d, 0, newData, this.data.Length, length);

                    this.data = newData;
                }
            }

            s.Close();
        }

        public bool isRunning()
        {
            return this.running;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            this.running = false;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            this.recvSocket.Close();
            System.IO.File.Delete(this.unixSocketpath);
        }

        public bool hasData()
        {
            return this.data.Length > 0;
        }

        public int dataLength()
        {
            lock (this.data)
                return this.data.Length;
        }

        public byte[] getData()
        {
            lock (this.data)
            {
                var d = this.data;
                this.data = new byte[0];

                return d;
            }
        }

        public byte[] getData(int length)
        {
            lock (this.data)
            {
                if (this.data.Length < length)
                    return this.getData();

                //var d = this.data.Take(length).ToArray();
                //var rest = new byte[0];

                byte[] taken = new byte[length];
                byte[] rest = new byte[this.data.Length - length];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(this.data, 0, taken, 0, length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(this.data, length, rest, 0, rest.Length);

                this.data = rest;

                return taken;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a litte program where you can see how to use the class:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using mps.unix.socket;


namespace TEST_mps.unix.socket
{
    class Program { static void Main(string[] args) { var P = new TEST(); } }

    class TEST
    {
        public TEST()
        {
            var v = new UnixSocket("/tmp/test.mps.unix.sock");

            Thread t = new Thread(delegate () { runner(v); });
            t.Start();
        }

        private void runner(UnixSocket s)
        {
            while (s.isRunning())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5);

                if (s.hasData())
                {
                    string responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(s.getData());
                    Console.WriteLine("Message received: {0}", responseData);

                    if (responseData == "END")
                        s.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled this with .Net 6.0 for linux-x64.

For testing run the software and then send something to the socket:

On server:

```
root@server:# ./test.mps.unix.socket
Message received: this is a message for the socket!
Message received: here is another one..
Message received: END
root@server:#
```

From another shell:

```
root@server:# echo -n 'this is a message for the socket!' | socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/test.mps.unix.sock STDIO
root@server:# echo -n 'here is another one..' | socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/test.mps.unix.sock STDIO
root@server:# echo -n 'END' | socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/test.mps.unix.sock STDIO
```

If you found bugs or can make improvements tell me and I will see if we can add it to the example :)