# How to use UnixDomainSocketEndPoint to create a unix socket in dotnet?

Tags: c#, c, .net-core, ipc, unix-socket

I have a program that was written on C that needs to send data to another application written on C#.

**Can someone show a basic hello world example on how to make use of [UnixDomainSocketEndPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.unixdomainsocketendpoint?view=netstandard-2.1) on linux?** . I will like the c# application to be the server. In other words the C application will send data to the C# application. **How can I create a unix socket that will be listening for data on dotnet (the application does not need to reply nothing back) ?**

---

When researching on the internet all the stuff I find is relevant to mono such as this question:
[How to connect to a Unix Domain Socket in .NET Core in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195290/how-to-connect-to-a-unix-domain-socket-in-net-core-in-c-sharp) . I tried that example and it did not work. Moreover it does not make use of UnixDomainSocketEndPoint.

I also found this tutorial https://medium.com/@goelhardik/http-connection-to-unix-socket-from-dotnet-core-in-c-21d19ef08f8a that uses the same code.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there are not that many examples on the internet because it is more simple than I thought. I was able to answer the question without researching on the internet. I should had tried it before asking. Anyways here is the answer:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = "/tmp/foo.sock";

        // client
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // wait 2 seconds
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified))
            {
                socket.Connect(new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(path));

                // send hello world
                var dataToSend = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello-world!");

                socket.Send(dataToSend);
            }
        });

        // Server
        {
            // delete file if it exists
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);

            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified);
            socket.Bind(new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(path));
            socket.Listen(5);
            Console.WriteLine("Server started waiting for client to connect...");

            var s = socket.Accept();

            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");

            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            var numberOfBytesReceived = s.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

            var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesReceived);

            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {message}");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: in your experience do you think this is less error prone in comparison to UdpClient class ? especially with this issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30782